# How to make a token(made by quanteda)convert to dataframe and have a doc_id per doc? i need a dataframe or tibble to calcuate tf-idf

Tags: r, tidyverse, quanteda

[image]

At frist, I used readtext() and as_tibble() got a tibble just like the picture shows.

And actually I want a one-token-per-row to calcuate the tf-idf (by per doc_id).

There have two question I met.
1.I found the function tokens() which from quanteda  can not be used in a a tibble(
2.I tried make it as a corpus()firstly ,and tokens()it then ,but I found the tokens format can not be coverted to be a dataframe or a tibble which i want made me so sad)

I want a tibble like that:

```
doc_id   word  n
xxx     xx     3
xxx     xx     40
xxx     xx     80



suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(quanteda)
  library(quanteda.textstats)
  library(jiebaR)
  library(readtext)
  library(purrr)
  library(tidyverse)
  library(RMeCab)
  library(tidyverse)
  library(tidytext)
  library(RcppMeCab)})


    ##readtext read all file 
docs1 <- readtext("/Users/oushiei/Downloads/NORUBY") 
class(docs1)##"readtext"   "data.frame"

     ##1.corpus
docs2 <- corpus(docs1) 
docs3 <- docs2 %>% tokens(remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE) ##"corpus"变为"token"
unnest(docs3)##error,no applicable method for 'unnest' applied to an object of class "tokens"

    ##2.tibble
doc_tibble <- docs1 %>% as_tibble()
doc_tibble
```

Comment: I am very sorry for the layout and my bad English .

Comment: check `dfm_tfidf` in quanteda.